# MyPy complains about datetime difference

Tags: python, datetime, mypy, arrows

MyPy complains about the line of code where bar is assigned the difference of two datetimes.

The type of foo is datetime.timedelta.

The error message from MyPy is "int not callable".

What am I missing?

```
import arrow

t1 = arrow.now()
t2 = arrow.now()
foo = t1 - t2
bar = foo.total_seconds()
```

Comment: `arrow` either doesn't have type hints, or you haven't told mypy where they are, so python assumes `a - b` is integer subtraction

Comment: are you sure the error comes from one of these lines?

Comment: arrow lib has type annotations, and there is nowhere above that mypy could get confused and think you are calling an int, so I think the error is in your real code but not in the question

Comment: @joel I don't think that's how it works, if MyPy doesn't have access to type annotations, it doesn't just assume it is working with `int` objects, why would it?

Comment: So, the problem is that `mypy` thinks `foo` is an `arrow.arrow.Arrow` object. This is probably a bug in the type annotations for `arrow`, though, not a `mypy` bug

Comment: Not sure though, here are the relevant type annotations: https://github.com/arrow-py/arrow/blob/4357f8c8dbdf8cf8c01a3f230873e19bd8a1a4d0/arrow/arrow.py#L1730 Actually, `pyright` handles this just fine... it *may* be a `mypy` bug.

Comment: @Aentropic, I am pretty sure. I commented the line where bar is assigned the datetime difference and mypy stopped complaining.

Comment: @Anentropic, I forgot to mention: the code actually works. The error is only from mypy.

Comment: you don't have to comment it out, mypy will tell you which line has the error when you run it (commenting it out may obscure the problem, error could be on another line)

Comment: You can write `reveal_type(foo.total_seconds)` and run mypy, it will tell you what type it thinks it is. We expect it to be a function (`Callable`) https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds ...if mypy think it's an `int` then that is very weird. But I suspect your real code looks a little bit different, maybe you have extra parens somewhere or something

Comment: Here are the things we tried: one of my colleagues tried running the exact same code on Mac and he did not get a mypy error. I am running on Windows. Also when I switched out the arrow.now() with datetime.datetime.now(), mypy stopped complaining. It looks like there is a bug somewhere.

Comment: Another thing: what I posted is the REAL code. By real I meant the exact same code that caused mypy error.

Comment: @Anentropic, you make a good point. After adding reveal_type, it looks like MyPy thinks the type of foo is arrow.arrow.Arrow. This is wrong. The actual type should be datetime.timedelta. So whose bug is this? mypy or arrow?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i don't know, but i've seen this behaviour a lot when working with tensorflow, though I can't remember if it was mypy or my IDE that was showing the error. Perhaps not relevant any more, given above discussion

Comment: @Anentropic no, this is a [mcve]. Again, I already posted what mypy is inferring about `foot`, that it is an `arrow.arrow.Arrow` instance, which has a `total_seconds` attribute, this might be due to `mypy` incorrectly resolving the overloaded type annotations of `arrow.arrow.Arrow.__sub__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a known issue. For details, see the following:

https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11613

Comment: Unless I am reading the ticket very wrong, this *isn't* a MyPy bug (it is merely *tracked* there). It would also help to include the key details in the answer itself, namely how to resolve the issue.